# Why it is a StackOverFlow Exception?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Why following code throws `StackoverflowException`?

```
class Foo
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: because each instance of `Foo` creates and instance of `Foo` which creates an instance of `Foo`....

Comment: Foo creates an instance of itself during initialization. That's infinite recursion.

Comment: Every new object is created on a stack. In your case you create infinite amount of objects and your application runs out of memory.

Comment: `[needed]` What is a StackOverflowException and how do I fix it? :)

Comment: 'StackOverflowException' is thrown when is infinite recursion is started, or big/deep enough to exceed stack size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `Main` you create a new `Foo` object, invoking its constructor.
Inside the `Foo` constructor, you create a different `Foo` instance, again invoking the `Foo` constructor.

This leads to infinite recursion and a `StackOverflowException` being thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Well, let´s see:

1. Program runs `main` which executes `new Foo();`;
2. `new Foo()` creates new `Foo` instance, including `Foo foo` field
3. `Foo foo = new Foo();`executes `new Foo` (go to step 2)